# Looping to create Python arrays

Tags: python, loops, numpy

I have this script to reduce an array to a smaller array, based on values in the 2nd column, then to calulate the mean of the 1st column in the resulting array.

```
ozone=np.array(ozone_1, float)
time=np.array(dectime_1)
a=np.column_stack((ozone, time))
b=a[a[:,1]==a[0,1]] 
c=np.nanmean(b[:,0])
```

I would like to be able to loop through this process for a range of values in the 2nd column (ie for when `a[:,1]==a[1,1], a[:,1]==a[2,1]`). And to also store the output somehow.
I'm really new to python so I have no idea how to write a loop yet! Here is my current attempt:

```
for a[i,1] in range(50):
    b=a[a[:,1]==a[i,1]]
    c=np.nanmean(b[:,0])
    print c
```

But this just gives the same value printed over and over

Comment: Here you go: [For Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using:

```
for i in range(50):
     b=a[a[:,1]==a[i,1]]
     c=np.nanmean(b[:,0])
     print c
```